# sregex_iterator не находит соответствий на строке

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

У меня есть строка - html код, который нужно распарсить с помощью регулярных выражений regex. Мне нужно записать в вектор std::vector все URL'ы на странице, находящиеся в `href=""`. Мой C++ код регулярных не работает.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::regex;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::sregex_iterator;
using std::smatch;

int main()
{
    string subject("<head><title>Search engines</title></head><body><a href=\"https://yandex.ru\">Yandex</a><a href=\"https://google.com\"></a></body>");

    try {
        regex re("<\\s*A\\s+[^>]*href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"");
        sregex_iterator next(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re);
        sregex_iterator end;

        if (next == end)
            cout << "Oops" << endl;

        while (next != end) {
            smatch match = *next;
            cout << match.str() << endl;
            next++;
        }
    } catch (std::regex_error& e) {
        ; // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Только Python'овский работает.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

html = '<head><title>Search engines</title></head><body><a href="https://yandex.ru">Yandex</a><a href="https:/google.com"></a></body>'

title = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>', html)[0]
links = [ x[1] for x in re.findall(r'<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["\'])(.*?)\1', html)]

print (title)
print (links)
```

Догадываюсь что можно просидеть неделю, листая справочник Джеффри Фридла по регулярным выражениям и библиотеке regex, и добиться нужного результата, но stackoverflow предназначен не для советов типа "читай Фридла, а не проси переварить кашу". К тому же на такой, казалось бы полезный вопрос, нет ответа на стэке, чтоб работало.

Comment: [парсить HTML с помощью регулярных выражений не выйдет, потому что HTML не является регулярным](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @VTT Предложите пожалуйста код с использованием std, boost или чего ещё

Comment: Попробуйте [gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправить код можно с помощью флага `std::regex_constants::icase`, а также использовании `sregex_token_iterator` с `1` в качестве четвёртого аргумента (для получения значения в захватывающей подмаске №1). В Python `re.findall` возваращает только захваченные подстроки, если в шаблоне указаны захватывающие подмаски, в C++ нет такого метода.

[Пример работающего кода на C++](https://ideone.com/eSaf6K):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    regex re("<\\s*A\\s+(?:[^>]*?\\s+)?href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"", std::regex_constants::icase);
    string subject("<head><title>Search engines</title></head><body><a href=\"https://yandex.ru\">Yandex</a><a href=\"https://google.com\"></a></body>");
    vector<string> result(sregex_token_iterator(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re, 1),
                               sregex_token_iterator());

    for( auto & s : result ) cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
// => https://yandex.ru, https://google.com
```

Comment: Вы просто загуглили ?

Comment: Что загуглил?...

Comment: Ну я к тому, как мне надо было найти эту страницу https://ideone.com/eSaf6K ?

Comment: Или этот сайт у вас в избранных ?

Comment: А, всё, понял. Это ваш код

Comment: Это нормально, что регулярки медленно компилируются ? (данный код 4 секунды)

Comment: @Антон Многое зависит от конкретной реализации библиотеки, от опций компилятора, да и сама регулярка не совсем оптимизирована. Кроме того, чем длиннее входная строка, тем дольше будет выполняться анализ. Ещё тут [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889886) был.